# Tech stack questions: Chat bot to database to show analytics and graphs

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, nosql, business-intelligence

Wanted some help with azure and the tech stack for this product.

We are building a chatbot using Skype integration to capture some unstructured data on which we plan to run reports on.
I am new to azure but wanted to use the capabilities it provides on Bi to generate some kind of insights and graphs. 
I am looking for a database service and a Bi service which is quick to integrate and isn't too expensive.
Let me know if there is something out there. I was considering elastic search with kibana, but I have never used this on azure and maybe the business user will find it a bit difficult to use kibana reports, I ve used it mainly for error reporting et Al. Let me know.